# error on connection to redis-server in chat messenger

Tags: python, redis

I have developed a chat system by Python. libraries been used :easygui,pycrypto,netifaces,stepic,redis,rabbitmq,pika,PIL and setuptools.
all libraries seems installed well refer to : python> import library
by using redis-server on localhost, users can connect to redis and signup,login,chat,.. but when setting redis on different device and change localhost to redis server ip in codes, i receive following errors. (am using lubuntu last version in oracle virtual machine)

```
enter code here
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "kiducb.py", line 392, in <module>
g = Gui()
File "kiducb.py", line 19, in __init__
self.welcome()
File "kiducb.py", line 33, in welcome
rl = self.login()
File "kiducb.py", line 126, in login
resp = self.check_up(fvals[0], fvals[1], mac)
File "kiducb.py", line 76, in check_up
val = self.re.get(username)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 423, in get
return self.execute_command('GET', name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 283, in execute_command
connection.send_command(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 260, in send_command
self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 243, in 
send_packed_command        
self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 191, in connect
raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting 10.1.1.12:6379. Connection refused.
```

Comment: is redis server running at all? can you connect to it from redis-cli?

Comment: yes and yes. while redis is running on localhost, everything is fine. but when i want connect to redis-server on other system( different ip) i recieve this error ... and kiducb.py which has apeared up there  is the main file to enter chat environment. firewall is off on both hosts and iptables is disabled on both virtual machnes. and both system have root access

Comment: I understand about the localhost, is redis running on remote host and can redis-cli connect to this remote host from the same machine as your app?

Comment: u mean i run redis;cli twice,once on client vm and once on server vm? and how should i connect redis-cli to server vm?

Comment: I mean, run `redis-server` on your remove machine, and try connecting to it using `redis-cli` from the machine where your app is running. something like `redis-cli -h 10.1.1.12 ping`

Comment: could not connect to Redis at 10.1.1.12:6379: connection refused  not connected>

Comment: and when i enter redis-server on the server machine, i receive this msg :


root@server-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/JSCS# redis-server
[8888] 18 Oct 18:18:07.577 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
[8888] 18 Oct 18:18:07.584 * Max number of open files set to 10032
[8888] 18 Oct 18:18:07.587 # Opening port 6379: bind: Address already in use

Comment: so the redis server is not running because it could not open port 6379. do you gave `redis-server` process running on the remote machine? `ps -ef | grep redis`

Comment: redis 1520 1 0 10:14 ? 00:03:34 /usr/bin/redis-server/etc/redis/redis/conf        and      root 2222 1763  0  10:21  pts/0   00:00:00 redis-cli    and     root 9339   2625  0  18:51  pts/2   00:00:00 grep --color=auto redis

Comment: seems like its running.PID :1520   user:redis

Comment: I would stop whatever is running there and make sure it runs on the right port.

Answer (score 3):

to solve this problem, i removed the redis-server which earlier i installed by useing apt-get from system, and i folowed this link instruction: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-redis

Comment: Thanks! You solved my problem which I was facing for last 2 days.